# Html Helper for IEnumerable<T> collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I have two classes `MyClassA` and `MyClassB`:

```
public class MyClassA
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyClassB
{
    public IEnumerable<MyClassA> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to create custom strongly typed html helper to generate textboxes with names from  collection `MyClassA`, something like this:

```
@model MyClassB

@Html.MyTextBoxFor(p => p.MapFrom(o => o.Age))
@Html.MyTextBoxFor(p => p.MapFrom(o => o.Name))
```

... with the output:

```
<input type="text" name="Age" />
<input type="text" name="Name" />
```

How can I accomplish this?

---

PS. I know, I can write sth like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Data.First().Name)
```

but it feels so wrong and inelegant...
Any ideas?

Comment: How is that inelegant? You can only pass one object to your view, so you either wrap everything in `MyClassB` or add icky ViewData. Not to mention your validation can still be handled this way.

Answer (score 3):

Let me make sure I understand this correctly... you want to create a textbox for `Name` and `Age` for each `MyClassA` in `Data` property of `MyClassB`. If so, then editor templates to the rescue.

Create `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyClassA.cshtml`

```
@model MyClassA

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age)
```

then in you view:

```
@model MyClassB

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Data)
```